# I want my riverpod autoDispose provider to dispose of itself only when page is closed, not when page is opened

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
final selectedCategoryProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose((ref) => '');
```

I have updated this provider with a category name and then navigated to the page where its value is used. Without autoDispose the value is preserved on going to the page but with autoDispose, it uses the default value of the provider.

I cannot do away with autoDispose modifier because I want its value to be disposed of when the page is closed and its updated value before opening the page to be preserved. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
onPressed: () async {
  final sub = ref.listenManual(selectedCategoryProvider, (_, __) {});
  ref.read(selectedCategoryProvider.notifier).state = ...;
  await Navigator.push(..);
  sub.close();
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Nice. This worked for me with a very similar use case. Where did you find out how to do this?

Comment: @chandler, I don't remember it now. Perhaps in one of the comments by Remi Rousselet somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you assigned the value on Page A and navigated to Page B.

Here you can attach an "empty" watch on Page A and your provider will not autoDispose. But the caveat is that you have to use `Navigator.push` so that Page A stays in navigator stack after you have moved to Page B or else Page A will. be removed from stack (in case of `Navigator.replace`) and you "empty" watch will also be removed.

You can use an empty watch like this:
`ref.watch(myProvider.select(() {}));`
[source](https://twitter.com/remi_rousselet/status/1493523352543285250)

The idea here is to attach a listener to your provider as long as you need it to not be disposed. A listener can be any of the following:

1. `ref.watch`
2. `ref.listenManual`
3. `ref.listen`